# Possible to pass a record through Rails redirect_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to manage user sign ups and log in with omniauth. I'd also like to collect more information about users after they authorize with the provider. At the moment `Vendor#from_omniauth` returns either an existing vendor or a new Vendor record with their auth hashes already populated. Is it possible to pass along the new record to the Vendor controller so the form can easily use it?

I'm using Rails 4.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    vendor = Vendor.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    if vendor.new_record?
      redirect_to new_vendor_url(vendor)
    else
      session[:vendor_id] = vendor.id
      redirect_to root_url, notice: "Signed in!"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: A redirect is a redirect; you either pass enough information to recreate the object via normal parameters, or drop it in session (if it's small and you're using cookies, or arbitrary size and you're using another session store), etc.

Comment: Have you had any luck with this? Did any of the solutions below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by changing `new_vendor_url(vendor)` to `new_vendor_url(vendor: vendor.attributes)`.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is stateless, so you'll need to either include info in the params, in the session (via cookies or other), or in the database.

Given that you seem to be doing a registration process, I might be inclined to put the info in the database as soon as you get it.  It's an additional write and then read, but if the user drops out midway through the process, you can still contact them (in theory) to resume the signup.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `vendor.id` to as an argument to `new_vendor_url`, then do the lookup in the rendered action:

```
# app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
redirect_to new_vendor_url(:vendor_id => vendor.id)

# app/controllers/vendors_controller.rb
def new
  vendor_from_session = Vendor.find(params[:vendor_id])
  # code here
  @vendor = Vendor.new
end
```